# How to merge object - lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am recently started using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs), I want to merge following objects.

### Object:

#### var firstObj =

```
{
   "1" : [
           {
             name: "karthick",
             age : 25
           },

           {
             name: "arun",
             age : 20
            }
         ],
    "2" : [
           {
             name: "varun",
             age : 25
           },

           {
             name: "smith",
             age : 20
            }
         ]
}
```

#### var secondObj =

```
{
   "1" : [
           {
             name: "gautham",
             age : 17
           },

           {
             name: "mathan",
             age : 19
            }
         ],
    "2" : [
           {
             name: "ashok",
             age : 16
           },

           {
             name: "dharani",
             age : 20
            }
         ]
}
```

#### Merged Object / Result:

```
{
   "1" : [
           {
             name: "karthick",
             age : 25
           },

           {
             name: "arun",
             age : 20
            },
           {
             name: "gautham",
             age : 17
           },

           {
             name: "mathan",
             age : 19
            }
        ]
    "2" : [
           {
             name: "varun",
             age : 25
           },

           {
             name: "smith",
             age : 20
            },
           {
             name: "ashok",
             age : 16
           },

           {
             name: "dharani",
             age : 20
            }
        ]
}
```

#### What i had tried:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n90vd215/)

Any suggestion will be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation you can read you have to use a customizer function that concats the arrays for you. (https://lodash.com/docs#mergeWith)

This method looks like this:

```
function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
  if (_.isArray(objValue)) {
    return objValue.concat(srcValue);
  }
}
```

Here's it used in your example:

https://jsfiddle.net/82koarwq/

*If you want to better understand what's happening inside the merge method:*

Merge takes the first object that it is passed as a base. It then loops through all the keys in the other objects it is passed (in order of arguments). It does two things:

- If the first object does *not* contain the key, it *adds* the key and its value.
- If the first object *already* contains the key, it *overwrites* its value.

By using *mergeWith*, you have the opportunity to overwrite this behavior. You can pass a method that is used to deal with the second case. If you want to fall back on the default merge behavior, you'll have to make your method return undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n90vd215/1/)

```
var output = {};
var firstObjKeys = Object.keys(firstObj);
var secondObjKeys = Object.keys(secondObj).filter(function(val){
  return firstObjKeys.indexOf(val) == -1;
});

var allKeys = firstObjKeys.concat(secondObjKeys);
allKeys.forEach(function(val){
  var firstArr = firstObj[val] || [];
  var secondArr = secondObj[val] || [];
  output[val] = firstArr.concat(secondArr);
})
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(output,0,4)
```